# How do I send chat transcript? SendConversationHistoryAsync() not working

Tags: c#, botframework

There is a sample for Conversation History: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history

Actually sending the transcript doesn't work in my attempts to run it. Specifically this line:

```
await connectorClient.Conversations.SendConversationHistoryAsync(activity.Conversation.Id, transcript, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

I get the following exception:

> ConversationHistory> fail:
>   Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.ConversationHistoryBot[0]
>   ConversationHistory>       Exception caught :
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was
>   canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of
>   either a thread exit or an application request. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted
>   because of either a thread exit or an application request
>   ConversationHistory>          --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   --- ConversationHistory>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
>   error) ConversationHistory>          at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16
>   token) ConversationHistory>          at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync() ConversationHistory>
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean
>   foldedHeadersAllowed) ConversationHistory>          at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ConversationHistory>
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ConversationHistory>          at
>   Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.ConversationHistoryBot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\Oyen\source\repos\BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\22.conversation-history\ConversationHistoryBot.cs:line
>   99 ConversationHistory>          at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs:line
>   105 ConversationHistory>          at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
>   ConversationHistory>          at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167

I can confirm that the transcript files are saved in my blob storage, and I can iterate through the activities retrieved from the blob.

(1) What am I missing to get SendConversationHistoryAsync() to work?

(2) What does the actual transcript look like when sent? (Is it worth it to just iterate through my activities and handle each activity type and make my own conversation history message?)

Comment: Which version of the emulator are you using? I was able to reproduce the `TaskCancelled` exception on emulator V3 (including the blob storage folder contaiing the transcript log), but the bot worked as expected on [emulator v4](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.1.0).

Comment: Regarding point 2, the actual transcript should appear as an array of activity objects in the method that confirms the API call was successful.

Comment: @MarkB I was using emulator V3. Thanks for the emulator V4 tip. I will shift to the preview V4 - looks like I've been missing out.

Answer (score 2):

The **ConversationHistory** sample functions as expected.  But, when using the **WebChat** or **Emulator** channels, the `Activity.Id`s must be updated.  Otherwise, the WebChat control will filter them out if already present:

```
bool updateActivities = new[] { Channels.Webchat, Channels.Emulator, Channels.Directline, }
                             .Contains(activity.ChannelId);
var incrementId = 0;
//get current id to ensure we do not overlap
if (updateActivities && activity.Id.Contains("|"))
{
     int.TryParse(activity.Id.Split('|')[1], out incrementId);
}

/* get activities */

foreach (var a in activities)
{
  incrementId++;
  a.Id = string.Concat(activity.Conversation.Id, "|", incrementId.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'));
  a.Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
  a.ChannelData = string.Empty; // WebChat uses ChannelData for id comparisons, so clear it
}

var transcript = new Transcript(activities);

await connectorClient.Conversations.SendConversationHistoryAsync(activity.Conversation.Id, 
                                transcript, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Those were good tips! Thank you. My problem was solved by using the v4 emulator instead of v3 as recommended in the comments above.