# How to fix a Bad Request while trying to display chat history with the BotFramework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to display the user's chat history with my bot so that when they come back they can see their previous conversations. When I'm trying the function "**SendConversationHistory(conversationId, transcripts)**" I keep getting a **Bad Request (400)** and the history is not displayed in the chatbot. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

**I'm using BotFramework SDK v.3 in C#.**

What I do is:
1. Checking if there is any conversation ID stored to be able to reconnect using that conversation ID
2. I send an event to the bot to restore the history
3. I'm able to fetch the previous activities and create the Transcript

After setting my transcript I tried this SendConversationHistory function which is not working.

I can chat with the bot even if this fails using the old conversation ID. I also tried to make the bot do a ReplyToActivity and this works.

I'm following [a js sample (v4)](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/eric/node_conversationHistory/samples/javascript_nodejs/22.conversation-history/bot.js), [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181825/how-do-i-send-chat-transcript-sendconversationhistoryasync-not-working) and [this thread about history in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/365) but none of it helped to solve this issue.

**MessageController.cs (in HandleSystemMessage)**

```cs
else if (message.Name.Equals("restoreHistory"))
{
    string convId = message.Conversation.Id;
    List<Activity> activities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Activity>>((string)message.Value);
    var incrementId = 0;

    if (message.Id.Contains("|"))
        int.TryParse(message.Id.Split('|')[1], out incrementId);

    foreach(var a in activities)
    {
        incrementId++;
        a.Id = string.Concat(convId, "|", incrementId.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'));
        a.ChannelData = string.Empty;
    }

    if (activities != null && activities.Count > 0)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        var transcripts = new Transcript(activities);
        connector.Conversations.SendConversationHistory(convId, transcripts);
    }
}
```

**default.htm**

```js
var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: ...,
    conversationId: getPersistedConversationId(),
    token: params['t'],
    domain: params['domain'],
    webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === "true"
});
BotChat.App({
    botConnection: botConnection,
    user: { id: ... },
    bot: { id: ... },
    speechOptions: speechOptions
}, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));

botConnection.connectionStatus$
    .subscribe(function (connectionStatus) {
        switch (connectionStatus) {
            case 2:
                if (botConnection.conversationId === localStorage.getItem('conversationId')) {
                    botConnection.postActivity({
                        from: user,
                        type: 'event',
                        name: 'restoreHistory',
                        text: '',
                        value: localStorage.getItem('conversations')
                    }).subscribe(function (activityId) {
                        console.log('sending chat history.');
                    });
                } else {
                    saveConversationId(botConnection.conversationId);
                }
        }
    });

function saveConversationId(conversationId) {
    localStorage.setItem('conversationId', conversationId);
}
function getPersistedConversationId() {
    return localStorage.getItem('conversationId');
}
```

The errors I get are those ones:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException' in Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll
Response status code indicates server error: 400 (BadRequest).
```

---

**Activities' Json**

```
[  
    {  
        "type":"message",
        "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h|0000001",
        "timestamp":"2019-06-19T10:37:40.1175096Z",
        "channelId":"directline",
        "from":{  
            "id":"MyBotName",
            "name":"MyBotName"
        },
        "conversation":{  
            "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h"
        },
        "text":"Hello, I'm MyBotName. How can I help you? To get started ask me a question.",
        "attachments":[  

        ],
        "entities":[  

        ],
        "replyToId":"7E6AtBm9iXL"
    },
    {  
        "type":"message",
        "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h|0000003",
        "timestamp":"2019-06-19T10:37:43.4034223Z",
        "localTimestamp":"2019-06-19T10:37:43.2484146+00:00",
        "channelId":"directline",
        "from":{  
            "id":"MyBotName",
            "name":"MyBotName"
        },
        "conversation":{  
            "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h"
        },
        "attachmentLayout":"carousel",
        "locale":"en-US",
        "text":"",
        "attachments":[  
            {  
                "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                "content":{  
                    "title":"Title1",
                    "subtitle":"",
                    "text":"",
                    "images":[  
                        {  
                            "url":"http://..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "buttons":[  
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button1",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        },
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button2",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                "content":{  
                    "title":"Title2",
                    "subtitle":"",
                    "text":"",
                    "images":[  
                        {  
                            "url":"http://..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "buttons":[  
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button1",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        },
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button2",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {  
                "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                "content":{  
                    "title":"Title3",
                    "subtitle":"",
                    "text":"",
                    "images":[  
                        {  
                            "url":"http://..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "buttons":[  
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button1",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        },
                        {  
                            "type":"openUrl",
                            "title":"Button2",
                            "value":"https://..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "entities":[  

        ],
        "replyToId":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h|0000000"
    },
    {  
        "type":"message",
        "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h|0000000",
        "timestamp":"2019-06-19T10:37:33.8526334Z",
        "serviceUrl":"https://directline.botframework.com/",
        "channelId":"directline",
        "from":{  
            "id":"anonymous",
            "name":"Anonymous"
        },
        "conversation":{  
            "id":"6Tklwkie30H7oCI1eyWx9i-h"
        },
        "recipient":{  
            "id":"MyBotName@WI6mwV4z0jY",
            "name":"MyBotName"
        },
        "textFormat":"plain",
        "locale":"en-US",
        "text":"i'm looking for this",
        "entities":[  
            {  
                "type":"ClientCapabilities",
                "requiresBotState":true,
                "supportsTts":true,
                "supportsListening":true
            }
        ],
        "channelData":{  
            "clientActivityId":"1560940638882.6146258363791712.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'm using DirectLine channel

Comment: Are you using Web Chat or a custom Direct Line client?

Comment: We're using Web Chat. We connect to the bot kind of like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline)

Comment: Are you using Web Chat v3 or v4?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I'm working in v3.

Comment: You said you're using Bot Builder v3. Since the activity schema remains unchanged, any Bot Builder version can be used with any Web Chat version. I still need to know what version of Web Chat you're using. If you edit your post to include the Web Chat code (JavaScript/HTML) I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: It's added but still sure it's version 3, like in the link I provided in one of my previous comments (that's where the information was, not in the post, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Try Web Chat v4 and see if that helps: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am working on multiple projects at the same time. I tried using WebChat v4 and I still have the same exception...

Comment: Did you check the transcript that you're passing in to make sure the activities all have unique timestamps and ID's?

Comment: Yes, I double checked and they all have unique ID's, unique timestamps. As you can see in my code, I increment their ID's based on my current message ID (following this [Eric Dahlvang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181825/how-do-i-send-chat-transcript-sendconversationhistoryasync-not-working) ). The only thing I saw while remote debugging was the "ReplyToId" which was not always filled in or matching the new ID's. Could it be a problem? In the Transcript documentation, it didn't seem like it was important... I can share the Json with my 3 activities if it helps.

Comment: Go ahead and share the JSON. I need all the details I can get to try and reproduce this.

Comment: I've posted the JSON in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're debugging in Visual Studio, you can click on "View Details" to see the whole exception object.

[image: View Details]

For an `ErrorResponseException`, you can see the actual error message that was returned in the HTTP response. In this case it says "Invalid activities" which makes it clear that something is wrong with the activities you're trying to send.

[image: Invalid activities]

It turns out you're not specifying the recipient of your activities. If you specify a recipient then you should get past your "BadRequest" exception.

*However*: There are a few more gotchas you might run into. Even if you don't get an exception, there are some things that can make `SendConversationHistory` fail without error while providing no feedback for why your activities aren't showing up in the chat.

Your strategy for populating the ID property is risky because your bot might send a message to the conversation before calling `SendConversationHistory`. If your bot had sent a message to the user during that same turn, it will have the same activity ID that you're trying to assign to the activity in the conversation history. This will cause a conflict and you won't see the activity show up. I recommend formatting the ID in some unique way that doesn't resemble the ID values that Direct Line automatically generates.

I was able to send your activities successfully by modifying the code like this:

```
foreach (var a in activities)
{
    incrementId++;
    // Use your own ID format
    a.Id = string.Concat("history|", incrementId.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'));
    a.ChannelData = null;
    a.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: convId);

    if (a.From.Name == message.Recipient.Name)
    {
        // If the activity was from the bot, assign the user as the recipient
        a.Recipient = message.From;
        a.From = message.Recipient;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the activity was from the user, assign the bot as the recipient
        a.Recipient = message.Recipient;
        a.From = message.From;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me displaying the activities from the bot. The one from the user are still not rendered. Even though I see them appearing at one point while I'm debugging the Javascript. Am I missing other properties on those? Thank you for having taken the time to answer and help me with this issue.

Comment: @Shamrock - I've updated the code so that each activity gets both its `From` and `Recipient` properties set. However, I tested the code by running it in response to a user-initiated message activity. If you're running the code in response to your own backchannel event from Web Chat, you need to make sure the event contains all the necessary information: `conversation`, `from`, and `recipient`. These should all match the current conversation and they likely won't match the conversation that the old activities are from. I'm checking the bot's name in the code because that'll likely be the same.

Comment: I tried adding From but it doesn't change the fact that user's messages are not displayed. Since my company decided to initialize users with "Anonymous" as name and id, I think the user's name in the current activity should remain the same as in the previous one, no?

Comment: @Shamrock - I can see that the backchannel activity you're sending to the bot does not contain a `recipient` property. You should either include that property or modify the C# to use an internally-stored bot name/ID instead of retrieving them from the activity.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I was on holiday. So I've been trying stuff because I still couldn't see the user chat and it appears that my version of botchat.js was the remaining problem. Thank you for your time and help because I probably would have not figured the recipient and from by myself. I'll mark your answer as correct.